# 3D Card Flip CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I cant seem to make the preserve-3d property value work. I am using the transform-style property and I have an h2 and a span in a div with a class of card-back and it is a descendent of the card div where I applied the tranform-3d property. I put a transform property on the H2 and the span to move it 400px forward in 3d space. but when I animate the card to see if the effect works via mouse hover the 3D effect does not work. What am I doing wrong? thank you

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

a {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:480px;
  height:298px;
}

.card {
  transform-origin: 0 149px;
  transition: .2s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  
}

.f-cta, h2 {
  font-family: 'Abel',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
}

.card-back h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.card-back h2, .card-back span {
 transform: translateZ(400px);
}

.f-cta {
  background: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 7px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.card-front, .card-back {
  width:480px;
  height:298px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

.card-front{    background:url(https://media3.giphy.com/media/IzcKEM2dAZpLxVZscO/giphy.gif);     
}

.card-back{   
    text-align:center; background:url(https://media0.giphy.com/media/jn8jaXRmHaHtY0K3xX/giphy.gif);     
}

a:hover .card {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<a>
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-front">
    </div> 
    <div class="card-back">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum project title</h2>
      <span class="f-cta">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    </div> 
  </div>
  
    
  
</a>
```